# Profiling build performance of Eclipse Maven Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, profiling

I'm using a modern version of Eclipse with few plug-ins on a powerful computer to build a rather small Maven-based Java project which also has one other Eclipse project as dependency<sup>†</sup>. Nevertheless, the build times for this project are atrocious — to the point that I even had to disable automatic building for the project, which I've never done before. **How can one profile the actual build process of an Eclipse project which uses Maven for building?**

### Environment

- Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Intel i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- Eclipse JEE Neon.1a Release (4.6.1), located on a traditional HDD
- Maven runtime 3.3.9/1.7.0.20160603-1931 embedded in Eclipse
- Java JDK 1.8.0_112 (64-bit), located on an SSD drive
- The Eclipse projects in question are located on the same HDD as the IDE itself

Based on these specs, I see no excuse for such slow build times and so I'd like to be able to find the bottleneck responsible for them.

---

<sup>†</sup>I haven't got control over the project which is a dependency, and unfortunately it hasn't (yet) been converted into to a proper Maven project... which also means I'm currently stuck building my project in Eclipse.

Comment: I guess your problem is "somewhere" within your statement that your project is "not a proper" maven project. I rather doubt that you get helpful advise here; have you tried asking within the eclipse forums? Besides: whatever you do here ... seems like spending time on a workaround. If you have a choice, better spent your time doing that "conversion into a proper maven project" yourself.

Comment: cant you make a JAR from the other project, install it into maven and then add a 'standard' dependency on it ?

Comment: First: What do you define as "slow build times"? How many modules / projects are you building? Furthermore are you building inside of Eclipse or on command line ? Apart from that to increase your build time you need to have all projects / eclipse etc. on SSD...Is this a plain java project or OSGi ? What kind of project? EAR/WAR files etc.? BTW: What do you define as build time?

Comment: @GhostCat I agree that the best solution is to clean up the dependency, but that is an entire project unto itself, as it's a mixture of Java, .NET and DLLs (requiring proprietary code and drivers). However, *that* project doesn't change at all, so at least in theory it should only be built once... or am I wrong?

Comment: Well, you said you had to disable auto-build; so I assume ... it builds constantly?

Comment: I mean of course I change *my* project