# Maven corrupts WAV file when copying to Java resource dir during build

Tags: java, maven, audio, build, wav

I've got a small Maven Java project which requires the playing of a WAV file, and so I'd prefer to simply put the file into the `src/main/resources/*` folder for simplicity. However, if  the same WAV file which works fine being loaded from disk using [`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream-java.io.InputStream-) is then put in the Maven resources directory, the program throws an instance of RIFFInvalidDataException:

```
com.sun.media.sound.RIFFInvalidDataException: Chunk size too big
    at com.sun.media.sound.RIFFReader.<init>(RIFFReader.java:82)
at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.internal_getAudioFileFormat(WaveFloatFileReader.java:65)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioFileFormat(WaveFloatFileReader.java:55)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:117)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1113)
    at se.kth.speech.coin.tangrams.TangramsClient.playSound(TangramsClient.java:276)
    at se.kth.speech.coin.tangrams.TangramsClient.signalGameStart(TangramsClient.java:335)
    ... 17 more
```

Moreover, if I use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to try to open the WAV file at `$PROJECT/target/classes/org/coolproject/audio/`, the program actually crashes; The original file is handled without any problems

What on Earth is Maven doing with my audio file(s)? I'm using version 3.3.9/1.7.0.20160603-1931 embedded in Eclipse Neon.3 v4.6.3 (build 20170314-1500) and unfortunately cannot try building the project with a "proper" Maven instance outside of Eclipse because building depends on [a nightmare hybrid of an old Eclipse project including both Java source and pre-compiled DLLs and a Java-only Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41440007/1391325).

Comment: `pom.xml` may be needed in order to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have filtering that has side-effects. As per the resources plugin's docs, you can disable filtering like this:

```
<project>
...
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
    ...
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
...
</project>
```

To see the docs, look [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the maven resources plugin is filtering your .wav file when it's being copied to the target directory. Check out https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html. You may have to add an exclusion to make sure that no filtering is being done on that particular file.